# Angular 5+ material date picker for Quarterly report

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need a code to customize the angular material date picker to display in the below format.

[image]

I need to achieve in angular 5 and I am fine with even selecting the year first and then the quarter. Please can someone help me

[EDIT] I could not achieve the below version. I tried to disable other months and display only start month of every quarter say JAN, APR ..

The code is

```
 <div id = "quarterPicker" class="innerContainer well-sm" [hidden]="isQuarterHidden">
      <app-custom-date-picker mode="QUARTER" label="Report Start quarter"  i18n-label=@@reportstartQuarter [(ngModel)]="chosenQarterDate" (ngModelChange)="kpiDateChanged($event,'quarter')"></app-custom-date-picker><br>
    </div>
```

-- in Custom date picker

```
  export class CustomDatepickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() mode: 'YEAR' | 'MONTH' | 'MONTHYEAR' | 'WEEK' | 'QUARTER' | '' | null;

@Input() label = '';

@Input() max: any;

@Input() min: any;

@Input() touchUi = false;

_yearPickerCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
_monthPickerCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
_regularPickerCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

 private _onDestroy: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  switch (this.mode) {
  case 'YEAR':
    this._subscribeToChanges(this._yearPickerCtrl);
    break;

  case 'MONTH':
  case 'QUARTER':
  case 'MONTHYEAR':
    this._subscribeToChanges(this._monthPickerCtrl);
    break;

  default:
    this._subscribeToChanges(this._regularPickerCtrl);

}

}
```

--In monthPicker.ts

```
  private _setupFilter() {
switch (this.mode) {
  case 'QUARTER':
    this._customFilter = (d: Moment) => {
      return d.month() === 0 || d.month() === 3 || d.month() === 6 || d.month() === 9;
    };
    break;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where's your starting point in code?

Comment: Hi @Roy , Attached the code

Comment: Hi All, Can someone help me please